# What is the reason chrome and firefox keep crashing after running this code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop an array and use a callback function to get the answer it works on the first callback second it the bug and dev tools crashes.

```js
var years = [1987, 1964, 1937, 200, 1954];
arrTotal = [];

function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrTotal.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return arrRes;
}

function calculatAge(el) {
  return 2019 - el;
}

function isFullAge(el) {
  return el >= 18;
}

var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculatAge);

// Bottom callback is the problem but why?

var fullAges = arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge);
console.log(ages);
```

I know it is the second callback function I just do not know why I spend most of the day googling for an answer.

Comment: your code indentation is .... absent ... making your code impossible to read

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare and initialize `arrTotal` inside of `arrayCalc`. Then return this array.

```js
function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
    var arrTotal = [];                     // declare and initialize with an empty array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arrTotal.push(fn(arr[i]));
    }
    return arrTotal;                       // return this array
}

function calculatAge(el) {
    return 2019 - el;
}

function isFullAge(el) {
    return el >= 18;
}

var years = [1987, 1964, 1937, 200, 1954],
    ages = arrayCalc(years, calculatAge),
    fullAges = arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge);

console.log(ages);
```

A bit shorter with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const
    arrayCalc = (array, fn) => array.map(fn),
    calculatAge = el => 2019 - el,
    isFullAge = el => el >= 18;

var years = [1987, 1964, 1937, 2010, 1954],
    ages = arrayCalc(years, calculatAge),
    fullAges = arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge);

console.log(...ages);
console.log(...fullAges);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand

Answer (score 2):

> Problem is due to `reference` and `push` ( which mutates original
>   array )

**Let's understand why it is happening**

- When you first calls ***`arrayCalc(years, calculatAge)`*** the **`arrayCalc`** return the reference of `arrTotal` ( Now ages holds reference of `arrTotal` )
- Now when you call ***`arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge)`***, you're push passing `refrence of arrToatl` in function (as ages is reference of arrTotal ) and inside your function you are looping through passed reference and pushing value in `arrTotal` so `arr.length` keeps on increasing and you end up in a `infinite loop`

So you can either define a new array inside your function so every time you call the function you're working on a new instance instead of reference

```js
var years = [1987, 1964, 1937, 200, 1954];


function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
 let arrTotal = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrTotal.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return arrTotal
}

function calculatAge(el) {
  return 2019 - el;
}

function isFullAge(el) {
  return el >= 18;
}

var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculatAge);

// Bottom callback is the problem but why?

var fullAges = arrayCalc(ages, isFullAge);
console.log(ages);
```

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation.

Comment: @JESSEJAMES11351 you can mark as correct answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see arrRes, so I suppose its not array, therefore ages will not be array as well.